# Wrapping a function which uses $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on some code which uses [jQuery Countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html). The plugin allows for a callback function to be passed which will be executed when the countdown hits zero:

```
{
    until: new Date(remaining),
    onExpiry: runSomeAction
}
```

`runSomeAction` uses `$(this)` to pick up the timer which hit zero. I'd like to wrap `runSomeAction` but the only way I know how to do this is to add a paramenter to it, like this:

```
{
    until: new Date(remaining),
    onExpiry: function() {
        // my logic here...
        runSomeAction($(this));
    }
}
```

But now I have to change all `$(this)` references in `runSomeAction` to the parameter name.

Is there a way to wrap `runSomeAction` so that it can continue using `$(this)` and I don't have to change it?

Comment: So what should the [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the `runSomeAction` call be, your countdown object literal? The `this` from that `onExpiry` callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) javascript functions to change the `this` context for a given function. Something like this should work for you:

```
onExpiry: function() {
    // my logic here...
    runSomeAction.call($(this));
}
```

Now within the runSomeAction function, `this` will equal `$(this)` from the point the function was called.

Answer (score 5):

I am not exactly clear what you are after. More code would have cleared up my answer.

You should be able to use jQuery's [`.proxy( function, context )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method.

Depending on what this scope you are after, it would either be

```
onExpiry: $.proxy(runSomeAction,this)
```

or

```
onExpiry: function() { runSomeAction.call(this); }
```

You could change it to `$(this)` in the proxy if you want the jQuery object.

Comment: They are the best. Quick question - in your second example, do you need to immediately call the function returned from proxy? The first example makes sense to me, but I'm wondering about the second

Comment: Ah, yes you need to call it! fixed! [maybe that was the downvote. lol]

Comment: The second example seems incorrect and also not preferable to me as well. Actually I 'd prefer a plain `.call` or `.apply` here. But here's +1 because I don't like mysteries.

Comment: And the second one exactly like call `call()` or `apply()`

Comment: @Jon, only reason why I have the second one is because I have no idea what the OP is trying to do. I actually think the first one is what the OP is after.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but this does not seem to answer OPs needs. He has some `// my logic here...` before calling `runSomeAction`, which is impossible with `$.proxy`. And that function expression is one of the worst things I've seen: Immediately replace it with `function() { runSomeAction.call(this); }`, and then replace that with just `runSomeAction` (assuming no return value and no arguments).